# cygwimでのgccコマンドやエイリアス

Tags: vim, cygwin

cygwinでvimを使うためにvimのパッケージを追加したり環境変数をいじってパスを通したりしていたのですが、いろいろやっているうちにエイリアスが使えなくなったりgccコマンドが使えなくなったりしてコンパイルができなくなってしまいました。
何が原因なのでしょうか。調べてみたのですが分かりませんでした。解決方法を教えてください。

Comment: 新しくcygwinを入れなおしたらパスを通さなくてもvimやエイリアスを使えるようになりました。
しかし、コンパイルがその他のコマンドの実行に3秒ほどかかりすごく重くなってしまいました。何が原因なのでしょうか。これでは作業に支障をきたします。
空き容量は23GB/100GBなので余り容量が足りないということではないと思っているのですがどうなのでしょうか...

Comment: 質問の主旨が変わってしまうので、速度面は別の質問として投稿なさるのが良いと思います。その際、具体的にどのようなコマンドを実行しているのかなど、具体的な問題の状況を書き添えると回答がつきやすいです。

Answer (score 2):

「いろいろやっているうちに」という条件で明確な答えを導くことは難しいです。エイリアスが使えないことに限っても、そのエイリアスを設定したファイルが読み込まれていなかったり文法エラーがあったり unalias されていたりと、考えられる原因はいくつかありますが、現状の情報だけだと判断がつきません。

幸運なことに今回は Cygwin 上での作業ということなので、必要なファイルだけ退避させた後 Cygwin を一旦削除し、もう一度セットアップすれば最初の状況に戻ることはできます。